# How to convert this function to Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

The errors are:
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSData'
and
Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

```
 class func loadMembersFromFile(path:String) -> [Member] //Function
{
    var members:[Member] = []
    var error:NSError? = nil
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options:[]), //data
        json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary, //my array (json)
        team = json["team"] as? [NSDictionary] { // display json
            for memberDictionary in team { //cylce for
                let member = Member(dictionary: memberDictionary)
                members.append(member)
            }
    }
    return members
}
```

Comment: please provide more informaion like: 
- what are you trying to achieve, fix your spelling as its a bit hard to understand what you want to do.
and welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use the `do catch` syntax for methods that can throw exceptions. Secondly, the `NSData` initializer doesn't produce an `Optional` value so you can't put it in an `if` statement.

```
class func loadMembersFromFile(path:String) -> [Member] //Function
    {
        var members:[Member] = []
        var error:NSError? = nil
        do {
            let data = try NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options:[])
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary,
            let team = json["team"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                for memberDictionary in team { //cylce for
                    let member = Member(dictionary: memberDictionary)
                    members.append(member)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            //handle exceptions
        }
        return members
    }
```

See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).